# Django return image and data in HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, http, request, httpresponse

I have a Django app working as the backend of an Android app. The thing is that the Android app sends an image to the Django server. Then the server makes some calculations and I need to return as the response the image modified and a float value that is calculated in the server.

It's pretty clear how to return only the image using HttpResponse:

```
def backend_function(request): 
    img = request.FILES["file"].read()
    img_res, float_res = some_calculations(img)
    return HttpResponse(img_res, content_type="image/jpeg")
```

But I don't know how to add that float_res to the HttpResponse.

Comment: You should use two responses. You can for example work with one response that returns the image data, and another with the `some_calculations`. An alternative is that you encode the image in some way, for example base64, and thus then return a JSON blob with the `float_res`, and with an encoded `img_res`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem's answer is right.  There may be other ways to consider.  You could append the `float_res` to the returned filename, or in the response header, or session.  If you are saving the image, you could return it as its URL, and both `url` and `float_res` could fit in the response.

Comment: @GAEfan, you're answer is the right one for me. I can just add the float to the header of the response and return it. Please write it down as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append the `float_res` to the returned `filename`, or in the response header, or session.